# How can i make a script for 2 button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make a script for 2 buttons, 1 button makes the paddle go up on the y and the other button makes the paddle to go down on the y in unity c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickExample: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button moveUpButton;
    public Button moveDownButton;

    [Space]

    public GameObject target;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        moveUpButton.onClick.AddListener(MoveUp);
        moveDownButton.onClick.AddListener(MoveDown);
    }

    void MoveUp()
    {
        target.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
    }

    void MoveDown()
    {
        target.transform.position -= new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
    }
}
```